# Stopping a deceased character from following you

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If a character dies whilst following you, are you therefore free to recruit a new follower? 
I have tried to recruit a new follower and each time I am informed that I currently "already have someone" when I do not.

I will certainly re-check the residence of my follower to see if perhaps they are still there but what are my options if this is not the case?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on PC, open the console and enter this command:

```
set playerfollowercount 0
```

This should fix this issue.

If you are on console, you must reload an earlier save.

Answer (score 1):

If playing on a platform that can use mods, using a mod like [**UFO - Ultimate Follower Overhaul** (PC)](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/14037)  or [**Amazing Follower Tweaks** (PC)](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/15524) / [Xbox One](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/4150200)  will allow you to have multiple followers, getting rid of the "*you already have someone*" message regardless if the deceased follower is still "following" you.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes followers get stuck behind locked doors or some other impasse when you leave the region and in to a new instance.

Unless you are sure they're dead, you can summon them to your position via the 'moveto' console command. This will allow you to dismiss them via the standard dialog options plus also recover any gear they were lugging around.

The benefit of this over the 'set playerfollowercount' method is that you'll know where your follower is should you need them in the future.